# Why does Kafka Streams app rebalances?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are deploying a Kafka Stream application using Kafka 0.11.0.2 against a single-node broker for testing purposes. The app keeps rebalancing, i.e. by listening to the state change using

```
kafkaStreams.setStateListener()
```

and logging, we typically see these lines:

```
18:06:15.222 State changed from RUNNING to REBALANCING
18:06:15.766 State changed from REBALANCING to REBALANCING
18:06:15.964 State changed from REBALANCING to RUNNING
```

If we increase the kafka.num.threads this occurs many more time before the stream application stabilize. What does trigger the rebalancing?